# What does the @Valid annotation indicate in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

In the following example, the `ScriptFile` parameter is marked with an `@Valid` annotation.

What does `@Valid` annotation do?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/scriptfile", method = RequestMethod.POST)    
public String create(@Valid ScriptFile scriptFile, BindingResult result, ModelMap modelMap) {    
    if (scriptFile == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("A scriptFile is required");        
    if (result.hasErrors()) {        
        modelMap.addAttribute("scriptFile", scriptFile);            
        modelMap.addAttribute("showcases", ShowCase.findAllShowCases());            
        return "scriptfile/create";            
    }        
    scriptFile.persist();        
    return "redirect:/scriptfile/" + scriptFile.getId();        
}
```

Answer (score 82, accepted):

It's for validation purposes.

> Validation It is common to validate a
>   model after binding user input to it.
>   Spring 3 provides support for
>   declarative validation with JSR-303.
>   This support is enabled automatically
>   if a JSR-303 provider, such as
>   Hibernate Validator, is present on
>   your classpath. When enabled, you can
>   trigger validation simply by
>   annotating a Controller method
>   parameter with the @Valid annotation:
>   After binding incoming POST
>   parameters, the AppointmentForm will
>   be validated; in this case, to verify
>   the date field value is not null and
>   occurs in the future.

Look here for more info:
http://blog.springsource.com/2009/11/17/spring-3-type-conversion-and-validation/

Comment: To make a long story short, in your particular example code, `ScriptFile` class has some constraints defined for the class data members like `@NotNull`, `@NotEmpty`, etc. and `@Valid` instructs the framework (spring in our case) to check these constraints against the parameter supplied when someone calls your method. In this case, if the validation fails, the server responds with an `HTTP 400 Bad Request` status code.

Comment: @EmreTapcı what will happen if we don't put valid? Won't it validate any constrain?

Comment: What happens if the the entity marked with @Valid is null?

Answer (score 45):

Adding to above answers, take a look at following. `AppointmentForm`'s `date` column is annotated with couple of annotations. By having `@Valid` annotation that triggers validations on the `AppointmentForm` (in this case `@NotNull` and `@Future`). These annotations could come from different JSR-303 providers (e.g, Hibernate, Spring..etc).

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/appointments", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String add(@Valid AppointmentForm form, BindingResult result) {
        ....
    }

    static class AppointmentForm {

        @NotNull @Future
        private Date date;
    }
```

Comment: I have a similar code. I had removed `@Valid` on `ApplicationForm` parameter but, still validations were fired on `date`(set as `null`)field. Please explain.

Answer (score 27):

I wanted to add more details about how the `@Valid` works, especially in spring.

Everything you'd want to know about validation in spring is explained clearly and in detail in https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/, but I'll copy the answer to how `@Valid` works incase the link goes down.

The `@Valid` annotation can be added to variables in a rest controller method to validate them. There are 3 types of variables that can be validated:

- the request body,
- variables within the path (e.g. id in /foos/{id}) and,
- query parameters.

So now... how does spring "validate"? You can define constraints to the fields of a class by annotating them with certain annotations. Then, you pass an object of that class into a Validator which checks if the constraints are satisfied.

For example, suppose I had controller method like this:

```java
@RestController
class ValidateRequestBodyController {

  @PostMapping("/validateBody")
  ResponseEntity<String> validateBody(@Valid @RequestBody Input input) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok("valid");
  }

}
```

So this is a POST request which takes in a request body, and we're mapping that request body to a class `Input`.

Here's the class `Input`:

```java
class Input {

  @Min(1)
  @Max(10)
  private int numberBetweenOneAndTen;

  @Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}$")
  private String ipAddress;
  
  // ...
}
```

The @Valid annotation will tell spring to go and validate the data passed into the controller by checking to see that the integer `numberBetweenOneAndTen` is between 1 and 10 inclusive because of those min and max annotations. It'll also check to make sure the ip address passed in matches the regular expression in the annotation.

side note: the regular expression isn't perfect.. you could pass in 3 digit numbers that are greater than 255 and it would still match the regular expression.

---

Here's an example of validating a query variable and path variable:

```java
@RestController
@Validated
class ValidateParametersController {

  @GetMapping("/validatePathVariable/{id}")
  ResponseEntity<String> validatePathVariable(
      @PathVariable("id") @Min(5) int id) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok("valid");
  }
  
  @GetMapping("/validateRequestParameter")
  ResponseEntity<String> validateRequestParameter(
      @RequestParam("param") @Min(5) int param) { 
    return ResponseEntity.ok("valid");
  }
}
```

In this case, since the query variable and path variable are just integers instead of just complex classes, we put the constraint annotation `@Min(5)` right on the parameter instead of using `@Valid`.

Comment: > So this is a POST request which takes in a response body, and we're mapping that response body to a class Input..... shouldn't it be POST request which takes in a "request body" ?

Comment: @sss: yeah, that was a mistake. It's been corrected now

Comment: @SomeGuy I'm just wondering what would it result if 
1.  I send the value as 'null' - @ Valid @ RequestBody Input input
2. I pass the value as 0 for numberBetweenOneAndTen

Comment: @EnthuCoder:  I'm not sure actually... I think null is considered valid, and if you don't want null to be considered valid, you'd have to use @ NonNull

Answer (score 26):

`@Valid` in itself has nothing to do with Spring. It's part of Bean Validation specification(there are several of them, the latest one being JSR 380 as of second half of 2017), but `@Valid` is very old and derives all the way from JSR 303.

As we all know, Spring is very good at providing integration with all different JSRs and java libraries in general(think of JPA, JTA, Caching, etc.) and of course those guys took care of validation as well. One of the key components that facilitates this is [MethodValidationPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api//org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/MethodValidationPostProcessor.html).

Trying to answer your question - `@Valid` is very handy for so called validation cascading when you want to validate a complex graph and not just a top-level elements of an object. Every time you want to go deeper, you have to use `@Valid`. That's what JSR dictates. Spring will comply with that with some minor deviations(for example I tried putting `@Validated` instead of `@Valid` on RestController method and validation works, but the same will not apply for a regular "service" beans).

Comment: But, what does validate?

Comment: Please elaborate, @nephewtom. What do you want to clarify?

Comment: I read JSR 303: Bean Validation, https://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/  but still I do not get what validation will be performed on `ScriptFile scriptFile`.

Comment: ScriptFile inside it probably has a bunch of fields and those fields have annotations on them as well. This is where the validation kicks in. Based on the original question it's not clear what exactly is inside ScriptFile class.

Comment: Ok, thanks.
Could you put an example of what could validate if its fields where a String, an Integer, and a Bean?

Comment: Like @Email(message = "Email should be valid") private String email if you use the latest specs where email support is added. Or @Pattern(message="Invalid pattern.", regexp = "^.+@.+\\.") private String pattern;

Answer (score 20):

IIRC @Valid isn't a Spring annotation but a JSR-303 annotation (which is the Bean Validation standard). What it does is it basically checks if the data that you send to the method is valid or not (it will validate the scriptFile for you).

Comment: What does it mean to "it will validate the scriptFile for you"? Check it is not null, it has some syntax, or some content? In other words, what does it validate and how? Should the user implement something? Where can I get info about it? Thank you!

Comment: Please answer @nephewtom's question, it's not enough answer to validate with the missing main point that is "against what"?

Answer (score 4):

```
public String create(@Valid @NotNull ScriptFile scriptFile, BindingResult result, ModelMap modelMap) {    
    if (scriptFile == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("A scriptFile is required");
```

I guess this `@NotNull` annotation is valid therefore if condition is not needed.

Answer (score 4):

I think I know where your question is headed. And since this question is the one that pop ups in google's search main results, I can give a plain answer on what the @Valid annotation does.

I'll present 3 scenarios on how I've used @Valid

Model:

```
public class Employee{
private String name;
@NotNull(message="cannot be null")
@Size(min=1, message="cannot be blank")
private String lastName;
 //Getters and Setters for both fields.
 //...
}
```

JSP:

```
...
<form:form action="processForm" modelAttribute="employee">
 <form:input type="text" path="name"/>
 <br>
 <form:input type="text" path="lastName"/>
<form:errors path="lastName"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form:form>
...
```

Controller for scenario 1:

```
     @RequestMapping("processForm")
        public String processFormData(@Valid @ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee){
        return "employee-confirmation-page";
    }
```

In this scenario, after submitting your form with an empty lastName field, you'll get an error page since you're applying validation rules but you're not handling it whatsoever.

Example of said error:
[Exception page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3qMN.png)

Controller for scenario 2:

```
 @RequestMapping("processForm")
    public String processFormData(@Valid @ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee,
BindingResult bindingResult){
                return bindingResult.hasErrors() ? "employee-form" : "employee-confirmation-page";
            }
```

In this scenario, you're passing all the results from that validation to the bindingResult, so it's up to you to decide what to do with the validation results of that form.

Controller for scenario 3:

```
@RequestMapping("processForm")
    public String processFormData(@Valid @ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee){
                return "employee-confirmation-page";
            }
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public Map<String, String> invalidFormProcessor(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex){
  //Your mapping of the errors...etc
}
```

In this scenario you're still not handling the errors like in the first scenario, but you pass that to another method that will take care of the exception that **@Valid** triggers when processing the form model. Check [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation) see what to do with the mapping and all that.

**To sum up**: @Valid on its own with do nothing more that trigger the validation of validation JSR 303 annotated fields (**@NotNull, @Email, @Size, etc...**), you still need to specify a strategy of what to do with the results of said validation.

Hope I was able to clear something for people that might stumble with this.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding to the above answer, In a web application
`@valid` is used where the bean to be validated is also annotated with validation annotations e.g. `@NotNull`, `@Email`(hibernate annotation) so when while getting input from user the values can be validated and binding result will have the validation results.
`bindingResult.hasErrors()` will tell if any validation failed.

Answer (score 2):

Another handy aspect of @Valid not mentioned above is that (ie: using Postman to test an endpoint) @Valid will format the output of an incorrect REST call into formatted JSON instead of a blob of barely readable text. This is very useful if you are creating a commercially consumable API for your users.