# @Valid annotation is not validating the list of child objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsr

Main model classes are as follows :

```
public class UserAddressesForm {

    @NotEmpty
    private String firstName;

    @NotEmpty
    private String lastName;

    private List<AddressForm> addresses;

    // setters and getters 

}
```

---

```
public class AddressForm {
    
    @NotEmpty
    private String customName;
    @NotEmpty
    private String city;
    @NotEmpty
    private String streetAn;
    @NotEmpty
    private String streetHn;
    @NotEmpty
    private String addressCountry;
    @NotEmpty
    private String postCode;
    
    // setters and getters
}
```

An endpoint in one of my controllers :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/up", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String completeForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("userAddressesForm") UserAddressesForm userAddressesForm,  
            BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest req) {

 // logic here 

}
```

A `.jsp` page :

```
<form:form commandName="userAddressesForm" action="registered">
    <table>

        <tr>
            <td class="formLabels"><form:label path="firstName">
                <spring:message code="label.name" />
            </form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="firstName" /></td>
            <td><form:errors path="firstName" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="formLabels"><form:label path="lastName">
                <spring:message code="label.surname" />
            </form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="lastName" /></td>
            <td><form:errors path="lastName" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    
    <c:forEach items="${userAddressesForm.addresses}" varStatus="gridRow">  
        <div id="main_address" class="address_data_form">
            <fieldset>
                <legend><spring:message code="label.stepThreeMainAddressInfo" /></legend>
                <a href="#" class="deleteItem"></a>
                <table>
                    <tr>            
                        <td class="formLabels">
                            <spring:message code="label.address.custom.name" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <spring:bind path="addresses[${gridRow.index}].customName">
                                <input type="input" name="<c:out value="${status.expression}"/>"
                                    id="<c:out value="${status.expression}"/>"
                                    value="<c:out value="${status.value}"/>" />
                                    <form:errors path="${status.expression}"/>
                            </spring:bind>
                        </td>   
                    </tr>               
                    <tr>            
                        <td class="formLabels">
                            <spring:message code="label.streetAnStreetHn" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <spring:bind path="addresses[${gridRow.index}].streetAn">
                                <input type="input" name="<c:out value="${status.expression}"/>"
                                    id="<c:out value="${status.expression}"/>"
                                    value="<c:out value="${status.value}"/>" />
                            </spring:bind>
                            <spring:bind path="addresses[${gridRow.index}].streetHn">
                            <input type="input" name="<c:out value="${status.expression}"/>"
                                id="<c:out value="${status.expression}"/>"
                                value="<c:out value="${status.value}"/>" >
                            <form:errors path="addresses[${gridRow.index}].streetHn"/>
                            </spring:bind>
                            
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>                        
                        <td class="formLabels">
                            <spring:message code="label.postCode" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <spring:bind path="addresses[${gridRow.index}].postCode">
                                <input type="input" name="<c:out value="${status.expression}"/>"
                                    id="<c:out value="${status.expression}"/>"
                                    value="<c:out value="${status.value}"/>" />
                            </spring:bind>
                        </td>                   
                    </tr>
                    <tr>                
                        <td class="formLabels">
                            <spring:message code="label.city" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <spring:bind path="addresses[${gridRow.index}].city">
                                <input type="input" name="<c:out value="${status.expression}"/>"
                                    id="<c:out value="${status.expression}"/>"
                                    value="<c:out value="${status.value}"/>" />
                                <form:errors path="addresses[${gridRow.index}].city" cssClass="error" />
                            </spring:bind>
                        </td>
                    </tr>       
                </table>    
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </c:forEach>
```

Why `@Valid` is not validating the `List<AddressForm> addresses` present in `UserAddressesForm` class ?

Answer (score 185, accepted):

You need to decorate `addresses` member of `UserAddressesForm` with `@Valid` annotation. See section 3.1.3 and 3.5.1 of [JSR 303: Bean Validation](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess). As I explained in my answer to the question [Is there a standard way to enable JSR 303 Bean Validation using annotated method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900077/is-there-a-standard-way-to-enable-jsr-303-bean-validation-using-annotated-method), this is the real use of `@Valid` annotation as per JSR 303.

**Edit**
Example code: [Hibernate Validator- Object Graph](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#d0e410). (The list of passengers in Car)

**Edit** From [Hibernate Validator 6](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=6.1#section-object-graph-validation) Reference doc:

> In versions prior to 6, Hibernate Validator supported cascaded validation for a subset of container elements and it was implemented at the container level (e.g. you would use `@Valid private List<Person>` to enable cascaded validation for `Person`).
>
> This is still supported but is not recommended. Please use container
>   element level `@Valid` annotations instead as it is more expressive.

Example:

```
public class Car {

        private List<@NotNull @Valid Person> passengers = new ArrayList<Person>();

        private Map<@Valid Part, List<@Valid Manufacturer>> partManufacturers = new HashMap<>();

       //...
   }
```

Also see what's new in [Bean Validation 2.0/Jakarta Bean Validation](https://beanvalidation.org/2.0/spec/#whatsnew-20).

Comment: What about grouping? I want address to be validated only when group A is validated. `@Valid` ignores the group.

Comment: @Akshay `@Valid` annotation works at the lower level. I think the [@GroupSequence](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/chapter-groups.html#section-defining-group-sequences) could be used to specify the validation order.

Comment: My detailed question http://stackoverflow.com/q/41457404/1534925. Don't think sequence would work in my case.

Answer (score 32):

Adding to @Ritesh answer, `@Valid` constraint will instruct the Bean Validator to delve to the type of its applied property and validate all constraints found there. Answer with code to your question, the validator, when seeing a `@Valid` constraint on `addresses` property, will explore the `AddressForm` class and validate all `JSR 303` constraints found inside, as follows:

```
public class UserAddressesForm {

    @NotEmpty
    private String firstName;

    @NotEmpty
    private String lastName;

    @Valid
    private List<AddressForm> addresses;

...
setters and getters 

public class AddressForm {

    @NotEmpty
    private String customName;
    @NotEmpty
    private String city;
    @NotEmpty
    private String streetAn;
    @NotEmpty
    private String streetHn;
    @NotEmpty
    private String addressCountry;
    @NotEmpty
    private String postCode;
...
setters and getters
```

Comment: What about grouping? I want address to be validated only when group A is validated. @Valid ignores the group

Comment: I didn't even read your answer but just looking at `setters and getters` solved my issue.

Answer (score 11):

In the  class UserAddressesForm add the following lines

```
@Valid
private List<AddressForm> addresses;
```

Answer (score 6):

Working solution.

```
public class UserAddressesForm {

    @NotEmpty(message="firstName is required")
    private String firstName;

    @NotEmpty(message="lastNameis required")
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull(message="addresses attributes are required")
    @Valid
    private List<AddressForm> addresses;

...
setters and getters 

public class AddressForm {

    @NotEmpty(message="customNameis required")
    private String customName;
    @NotEmpty
    private String city;
    @NotEmpty
    private String streetAn;
    @NotEmpty
    private String streetHn;
    @NotEmpty
    private String addressCountry;
    @NotEmpty
    private String postCode;
...
setters and getters
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented all the suggestions and annotated child field in the parent class with with `@Valid` but still the child entities were not getting validated.

Luckily it is resolved now and the issue was because of the dependency.
As a solution I used below dependency

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

instead of

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was `@NotNull`, in the child, and not a `@NotEmpty` annotation. I had to put a `@NotNull` before the `@Valid` annontation to make it work.

**like this:**

```
private List<@NotNull @Valid YourObject> yourObjects;
```