# Spring MVC : How To Get BindingResult Error Field for Nested Object

Tags: json, validation, data-binding, spring-mvc

I submit this data to add a Child entity via Ajax (POST):

*(See the bottom of this question for entity classes definition)*

```
name = "Child Name"
parent.id = 3
```

Everything is OK. The new Child entity is saved successfully.

But If don't include the `parent.id` (only `name` is set) (submitted using POST method)

```
name = "Child Name"
```

The validation result return this JSON:

```
"errors":{"parent":"may not be null"}
```

Note the `"parent"` property in that JSON. It's supposed to return `parent.id` not `parent`.

It causes problem as the field on client-side script (HTML) has the name `"parent.id"` not `"parent"`.

Any suggestion How to return `parent.id` instead of `parent` ??

Here is the handler method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, ?> add(@Valid Child child, BindingResult result) {

    Map<String, ?> out = new LinkedHashMap<String, ?>();

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        Map<String, String> errors = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        for (FieldError error : result.getFieldErrors()) {
           errors.put(error.getField(), error.getDefaultMessage());
        }
        out.put("success", false);
        out.put("errors", errors);
        return out;
    } else {
        out.put("success", true);
    }

    return out;

}
```

And here are the entity classes:

```
class Child {
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 5)
    private String name;

    @NotNull        
    private Parent parent;

    //getter and setter methods
}

class Parent {
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    //getter and setter methods
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for @oehmiche for the suggestion.

I end up changing the entity classes to these:

```
class Child {
    @NotNull
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 5)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Valid
    private Parent parent = new Parent("Foo Foo");

    //getter and setter methods
}

class Parent {
    @NotNull
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    public Parent(){
    }

    public Parent(String name){
         setName(name);
    }

    //getter and setter methods
}
```

And this is the submitted data:

```
id = 1
name = "Child Name"
parent.id = 3
```

**Note the `id` property**. I end up to always set this to 1 just to bypass the `@NotNull` constraint. Although the `id` value will always be replaced by Hibernate (I use auto generation strategy).

(I add `@NotNull` constraint for `id` of Parent as well as Child class for consistency)

However, there is still one problem. I have to always set parent's name just to bypass the validation constraint for `name` property of Parent:

```
@NotNull
@Valid
private Parent parent = new Parent("Foo Foo");
```

Any suggestion for this?

Comment: Use the @Validated annotation in the controller with a "validation group" http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#validationapi-validatorapi-groups

Answer (score 2):

According to the hiberante validation specification object graph validation is triggered using the `@Valid` on the property to be validate (in your case the `parent` property). But there is also mentioned that `null` values will be ignored (see the note below the [example](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html_single/#example-car-with-driver)).
So in your case I'd suggest to instantiate an empty `Parent` object in your `Child` class and annotate that one with `@Valid`:

```
@Valid        
private Parent parent = new Parent();
```

see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/5142960/160729

Comment: Thank you @oehmiche. I think your solution is right. But now it's validate the null `parent.name` instead of the null `parent.id`. Any further suggestion for this??