# javax validation on nested object with groups

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, bean-validation

Here is my java code

```
class AbstractO{
     public interface Save{}; // for groups
     public interface Update{}; // for groups
}
class A extends AbstractO{
     public Integer id;
     @NotNull(groups={A.Save.class})
     @Valid
     public B b;
}
class B extends AbstractO{
     @NotNull(groups={B.Update.class})
     public Integer id;
     @NotNull(groups={A.Save.class})
     public Integer prop

}
```

// controller method

```
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<A> save(@RequestBody @Validated(value = { A.Save.class }) A ,
            BindingResult bindingResult) {
// code goes here...
}
```

*Issue*

At time of saving A I want to have validation. Validation group is set as `A.Save` in controller method so `B b` in class `A` is is getting validated as notnull.

However I want to have validation of `prop` of class `B` while saving `A`, So I have added `@Valid` on `B b` and mentioned group `A.Save` on prop so that validate that only when A is getting saved.

My problem is even `id` of B has on `B.Update` as group, it still validates in controller (with group `A.Save`). May be issue is the `@Valid` annotation but without that annotation it does not validates nested things.

Comment: That behavior sounds like a bug somewhere. Is there any chance you provide an isolated test case (ideally only containing Bean Validation and nothing else)?