# The Spring validation @NotNull does not validate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-validator

I’m trying to validate a POST request using Spring Validator. This is the Object I’m trying to validate:

```
@Validated
public class Request implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id1;
    private Long id2;   
    private String s;   
    private List<Mapping> mappings;

    public Request() {}
    public Request (Long id1, Long id2, String s, List<Mapping> mappings) {
        this.id1 = id1;
        this.id2 = id2;
        this.s = s;
        this.mappings = mappings;
    }

    //getter() and setter() methods.
}
```

And this is the Mapping class:

```
@Validated
public class Mapping implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @JsonProperty(value="id")
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty(value="string")
    private String string;

    @JsonProperty(value="account_id")
    @NotNull
    private String accountId;

    @JsonProperty(value="last_updated_at")
    @NotNull    
    private OffsetDateTime lastUpdatedAt;

    // Getter and setters()
    // I'll skip the getter() and setter() for id and string fields.
    @Override
    public String getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAccountId (@NotNull String accountId) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }

    @Override
    public OffsetDateTime getLastUpdatedAt() {
        return lastUpdatedAt;
    }

    @Override
    public void setLastUpdatedAt(@NotNull OffsetDateTime lastUpdatedAt) {
        this.lastUpdatedAt = lastUpdatedAt;
    }
}
```

This is the message being posted:

```
[Request [id1=null, id2=null, s=6eq2J6, mappings=

[Mapping [id=2779, string=6eq2J6, accountId=null, lastUpdatedAt=null]]]]
```

This is how I receive the request, but the bindingResult.hasErrors() is always empty. The pushRequest is exactly as it was sent.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/${path}", method={RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT})
@Validated
public class MappingController {

@PostMapping(value="/", consumes={"application/json"})
public void processMappings (@Valid @RequestBody Optional<Request> pushRequest, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        log.info("Error!");
    }
}
}
```

Why the `@NotNull` for accountId and lastUpdatedAt does not make the validation to fail when they have `Null` value?

I've tried to find the solution by searching this error, the solutions was to add `@Validated` to the `Request, Mapping and MappingController` classes, which did not solve the problem.

Another solution was to add these `Beans` to the `Main()` class, which did not solve the problem.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);        
        //System.out.println("version: " + SpringVersion.getVersion()); // version: 5.1.0.RC1
    }

    @Bean
    public javax.validation.Validator localValidatorFactoryBean() {
       return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
                MethodValidationPostProcessor mvProcessor = new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
                mvProcessor.setValidator(validator());
                return mvProcessor;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
                    LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
                    validator.setProviderClass(HibernateValidator.class);
                    validator.afterPropertiesSet();
                    return validator;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSR-303 @Valid annotation (nested object) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142065/jsr-303-valid-annotation-nested-object-not-working)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I found the answer thanks to this post:

[jsr-303-valid-annotation-nested-object-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142065/jsr-303-valid-annotation-nested-object-not-working)

So as soon as I added the @Valid to these fields:

```
@Valid
private List<Mapping> mappings;
```

And these fields inside Mapping:

```
@JsonProperty(value="account_id")
    @Valid
    @NotNull
    private String accountId;

    @JsonProperty(value="last_updated_at")
    @Valid
    @NotNull    
    private OffsetDateTime lastUpdatedAt;
```

The validation started working.

Also I removed the `@NotNull` in the `setter()` methods:

Setters() like this:

```
@Override
    public void setAccountId (String accountId) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }    

    @Override
    public void setLastUpdatedAt(OffsetDateTime lastUpdatedAt) {
        this.lastUpdatedAt = lastUpdatedAt;
    }
```

Also my code worked without any of the Validator beans which I added to Main().

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I was missing the validation dependency. From [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation);

`Starting with Boot 2.3, we also need to explicitly add the spring-boot-starter-validation dependency:`

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```