# Validation a DTO with two entity

Tags: java, validation

I have a DTO with two entity. How can I validate these entities?
What annotation should I use?
I use rest api, JSON, spring boot.
I know how to validate one entity. But I don't know what to do with DTO.

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> create(@Valid @RequestBody DTOClient client) {
       ....

        return responseEntity;
    }

public class DTOClient{

//What I should use here to validate these entities?
    private Client client;
    private Skill skill;

}

@Entity
public class Client{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String first_name;

    private String last_name;
}

@Entity
public class Skill{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private int year;
}
```

Comment: use `javax.validation`

Comment: I know, you to use it in entities. But need I to annotate DTO or/and fields in DTO?

Comment: No need to add annotation on DTO but you need to add annotation on Cline and Skill entity. ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142065/jsr-303-valid-annotation-nested-object-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `javax.validation` for the fields which you want to validate. Below code is an example to validate `first_name` in `client` object should not null or blank.

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> create(@Valid @RequestBody DTOClient client) {
       ....

        return responseEntity;
    }

public class DTOClient{

//What I should use here to validate these entities?
    @Valid
    @NotNull(message="client should not null")
    private Client client;
    private Skill skill;

}

@Entity
public class Client{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @NotBlank(message="first name of client should not be null or blank")
    private String first_name;

    private String last_name;
}

@Entity
public class Skill{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private int year;
}
```

In short, you need use `@Valid` for Bean, like controller methods' params and the fields which not primary.  And Constraint annotations for the fields which need validate.