# Spring Boot - Validation on related entity one to many relationship

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Supposed I have a User entity and it has a one to many relationship with Post

```
@OneToMany(
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY
)
@JoinColumn(
        name = "user_id",
        foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk"),
        referencedColumnName = "userId")
private List<Post> post = new ArrayList<>();
```

and this is my `Post` entity

```
@NotBlank(message = "test")
@Column(length = 50)
private String title;

@Column
private String post;
```

How can I validate the Post when Im inserting a new user? For example this what I passed on the request

```
{
        "name": "Test name",
        "username": "Test username",
        "post": [
            {
                "title": "asdasd",
                "post": "asdasd"
            }
        ]
}
```

If I pass a blank string on title

```
"title": "",
```

Im getting an error

```
Validation failed for classes .... during persist time for groups
```

Comment: Can you provide more context for the error, maybe a stack trace?

Comment: Validation failed for classes [com.test.app.api.models.Post] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]\nList of constraint violations:[\n\tConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='test', propertyPath=title, rootBeanClass=class com.test.app.api.models.Post, messageTemplate='test'}\n]

Answer (score 0):

Did you add @Valid annotation for post method?
Example:

```
 @PostMapping("/user")
 User insertNewUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
    // Do something
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `@Valid` annotation to the `post` member of the `User` model. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5142960/12431728

Comment: im getting the error message now however "post[0].title : test" should be "post.title : test"