# @Valid annotation is not validating the list of child objects - Spring Boot + Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I have a very similar problem to this topic [@Valid annotation is not validating the list of child objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142065/valid-annotation-is-not-validating-the-list-of-child-objects) but trying to implement using Kotlin.

The `@Valid` annotation is not working for `WordDto`. Only the class `MessageDto` is evaluated.

```kotlin
@SpringBootApplication
class ValidationsApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<ValidationsApplication>(*args)
}

data class WordDto(
    @field:Max(5)
    val word: String
)

data class MessageDto(
    @Valid
    @field:NotEmpty
    val words: List<WordDto>
)

@RestController
class Controller {
    @PostMapping("/hello")
    fun hello(@Valid @RequestBody messageDto: MessageDto) {
        messageDto.words.map(System.out::println)
    }
}
```

I've tried this approach too:

```kotlin
val words: List<@Valid WordDto>
```

Also wrote this test that should be passing:

```kotlin
@Test
    fun `should validate child objects`() {
        val dto = MessageDto(
            words = listOf(
                WordDto("Long Word that should fail")
            )
        )

        val violations = validator.validate(dto)

        assertThat(violations).isNotEmpty()
    }
```

Dependencies:

```
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
```

Any ideas of what could be missing?

The project can be found in [Github](https://github.com/rribeiro1/spring-kotlin-validations)

Comment: `@Valid` => `@field:Valid` in MessageDto class

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko thank you so much, this is what was missing!

Answer (score 1):

Following the `@NikolaiShevchenko`'s answer, this is the solution.

```kotlin
data class MessageDto(
    @field:Valid
    @field:NotEmpty
    val words: List<WordDto>
)
```