# Spring MVC form validation does't work for nested complex types

Tags: java, spring, forms, validation, spring-mvc

I am implementing a sample Spring MVC Form with Form Validation. I have a complex type `Address` as bean property for `Student` form bean. And I have added form validation `@NotEmpty` for `Address` bean properties. But the same is not reflecting in the UI. But form validation works for other primitive types of `Student` form bean.

So, Validation works perfectly for `Student` form bean but not for nested complex types like `Address` within `Student` form bean.

I am trying understand the reason and a fix.

Spring version 4.0+.
Hibernate Validator api:5.2.4

`Student` POJO:

```
package com.xyz.form.beans;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.constraints.Past;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

import com.xyz.validators.DateNotEmpty;
import com.xyz.validators.ListNotEmpty;

public class Student {
    @Size(min = 2, max = 30)
    private String firstName;
    @Size(min = 2, max = 30)
    private String lastName;
    @NotEmpty
    private String gender;
    @DateNotEmpty
    @Past
    private Date DOB;
    private String email;
    private String mobileNumber;
    @ListNotEmpty
    private List<String> courses;
    private Address address;

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public Date getDOB() {
        return DOB;
    }

    public void setDOB(Date dOB) {
        DOB = dOB;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getMobileNumber() {
        return mobileNumber;
    }

    public void setMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }

    public List<String> getCourses() {
        return courses;
    }

    public void setCourses(List<String> courses) {
        this.courses = courses;
    }
}
```

`Address` POJO:

```
    package com.xyz.form.beans;

    import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

    import com.xyz.validators.LongNotEmpty;

    public class Address {
        @NotEmpty
        private String houseNo;
        @NotEmpty
        private String street;
        @NotEmpty
        private String area;
        @NotEmpty
        private String city;
        @LongNotEmpty
        private Long pin;

        public String getHouseNo() {
            return houseNo;
        }

        public void setHouseNo(String houseNo) {
            this.houseNo = houseNo;
        }

        public String getStreet() {
            return street;
        }

        public void setStreet(String street) {
            this.street = street;
        }

        public String getArea() {
            return area;
        }

        public void setArea(String area) {
            this.area = area;
        }

        public String getCity() {
            return city;
        }

        public void setCity(String city) {
            this.city = city;
        }

        public Long getPin() {
            return pin;
        }

        public void setPin(Long pin) {
            this.pin = pin;
        }
    }
```

`Student` Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/newStudentDetails.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView newStudentDetails(
                @Valid @ModelAttribute("student") com.xyz.form.beans.Student studentFormBean,
                BindingResult bindingResult) {
            if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
                return new ModelAndView("newStudentPage");
            }
            Student studentDto = new Student();
            studentDto.setFirstName(studentFormBean.getFirstName());
            studentDto.setLastName(studentFormBean.getLastName());
            studentDto.setGender(studentFormBean.getGender());
            studentDto.setDOB(new Date(studentFormBean.getDOB().getTime()));
            studentDto.setEmail(studentFormBean.getEmail());
            studentDto.setMobileNumber(studentFormBean.getMobileNumber());
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(studentFormBean.getAddress().getHouseNo() + ", ");
            sb.append(studentFormBean.getAddress().getStreet() + ", ");
            sb.append(studentFormBean.getAddress().getArea() + ", ");
            sb.append(studentFormBean.getAddress().getCity() + "-");
            sb.append(studentFormBean.getAddress().getPin());
            studentDto.setAddress(sb.toString());
            studentDto.setCourses(studentFormBean.getCourses());
            studentDao.createStudent(studentDto);
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("newStudentSuccess");
            return mav;
        }
```

Thanks,
Viswanath

Comment: And you happily don't include the classes concerned... Add them to your question.

Comment: Please find the code added. Let know if you have a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nested objects require a `@Valid` annotation as expressed in the JSR-303 spec. So put `@Valid` on the `Address` field in `Student`.

Comment: Perfectly works. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 5):

You need to annotate your complex types with @Valid.
[This is the reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142065/problem-with-valid-annotation-nested-object) (which references [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900077/is-there-a-standard-way-to-enable-jsr-303-bean-validation-using-annotated-method))

Answer (score 1):

Hi lets try `@ModelAttribute("student") @Valid com.xyz.form.beans.Student studentFormBean` in place of `@Valid @ModelAttribute("student")`

Answer (score 0):

For nested complex types, you have to activate the direct field access. Just like below:

```
@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerAdvice {

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder webDataBinder) {
        webDataBinder.initDirectFieldAccess();
    }
```