# How to know that field is not passed

Tags: java, rest, serialization

Here is an example DTO

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class TestDto {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String sex;
}
```

Say I have this object stored on the server:
`{"id":1, "name": "alex", "sex": "M"}`

How can I send a request that only updates the "name" portion of the object?

Perhaps I could send this:
`{"id":1, "name":"adam"}`

Such that the object will change to this:
`{"id":1, "name": "adam", "sex": "M"}`

I also need the ability to set a field to null
(i.e. clear the contents of a field).

In this case I would like to send
`{"id":1, "name":"adam", "sex":null}`

To have the stored DTO change to
`{"id":1, "name": "adam", "sex":null}`

How can I do this using java, spring boot, etc.?

I know the way to use:

```
@PutMapping
public TestDto update(Map<String, Object>map){ ... }
```

but I also need to some validation such that if I pass
`{"id":"1AA" ... }` I get a serialization exception.

Ps.Find first step of this magic ->
1.Before path TestDto throu Rest - need to clear Type like this

```
Object body = testDto;
```

if will help you to get an Object with field what you want on server and then you'll be able to detect list of fieds to update

Comment: There are several mapping libraries (e.g. http://modelmapper.org) that can update fields of existing objects from other similar objects. That would allow you to define [validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595160/what-does-the-valid-annotation-indicate-in-spring) on TestDto as required and would allow you to merge data when it's for example `!= null`. Or you can simply write out the code to copy the present properties into the existing object (e.g. a `updateFrom(TestDto other)` method)

Comment: the question was how to detect that field is not passed from client - serializer will  init this field with null and that its not what i need - i need set null value if clien pass null and do not set anything if client do not pass field

Comment: Ah, sorry misunderstood the null part. Yeah, that's tricky, maps or defining a structure that contains explicit information about adding / removing fields, like `{ set: TestDto; remove: TestDto; }`

Comment: it may be looks like this  @PutMapping
    public TestDto update(@RequestBody Map<String, Object>map){

        val oldValue = cash.get((Long) (map.get("id")));
        if(map.containsKey("name")) oldValue.setName((String) map.get("name"));
        if(map.containsKey("sex")) oldValue.setName((String) map.get("sex"));
       return cash.put(oldValue.getId(), oldValue);

    }

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attempting to detect absent vs null value,
consider defining an update object that includes a list of fields to be updated.

Such an object might look like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class UpdateObject
{
    private long id; // ID of the object to be updated.
    private TestDto updates; // an object that contains the new values for the fields.
    private List<String> updateFields; // a list of fields to be updated.
}
```

Here is some Json

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "updates":
    {
        "name": "blem",
        "sex": null
    },
    "updateFields": ["name", "sex"]
}
```

Comment: and how to pass that json? if server wait for TestDto....

Comment: change your server to expect the new JSON.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood right you just send request to the server with different fields. With `@ModelAttribute` annotation you can send your body in json format.
if you send only one/two field or how you want `{"id":1, "name":"adam"}`, due to spring data jpa you can update your model in db. (in this case your field `sex` will be null and you need to create some manipulation for checking it kind of Mapstruct - convert your dto in other model plus checking null/not null fields).
Better create default value for `sex` field if you want to saving not M and not FM values. null bad practice, in the future it will be bad joke for you.

@Getter
public Enum Sex {
private MALE,
private FEMALE,
private DEFAULT
}

Comment: no you dnt understand - i need to 3 states - null, not null, do not pass.Thant means if i pass name = null , name should be updeted with null , if i do not pass name it will stay like it was and if i pass name = "alex" it should be changed to alex, but serializer init the fields without value as null and this is  what i want to change - may be using some custom serializer

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys finally fount how to do this

1.Client side - > path your testDto as Object, not as TestDto.class

```
Object payLoad = testDto;
template.postForObject("url", payload);
```

2.Server side - >

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

    private final Map<Long, TestDto> cash = new HashMap<>();
    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @PostMapping
    public TestDto create(@RequestBody TestDto dto) {
        return cash.computeIfAbsent(dto.getId(), v -> dto);

    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public TestDto update(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody String json) throws JsonProcessingException {
        val oldValue = cash.get(id);
        mapper.readerForUpdating(oldValue).readValue(json);
        return cash.put(oldValue.getId(), oldValue);
    }

}
```

this hint let you update only field that client really changed