# Spring boot how to access nested object custom field validation as FieldError?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, error-handling

I can validate a nested object using an annotation and validator, implementing `ConstraintValidator`. The code has a conditional validation statement, where it should validate a nested object.

It is done like so:

```
 @Override
    public boolean isValid(ScheduleJobRequest value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (value.getJobType() != JobType.EXPORT) {
            return true; // do not fail
        }
        final ExportRequestData exportData = value.getExportData();
        if (exportData == null) {
            context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
            context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("NotEmpty")
                    .addPropertyNode("exportData").addConstraintViolation();
            return false;    
        }
        
        final Set<ConstraintViolation<ExportRequestData>> violations = validator.validate(exportData);
        violations.forEach(violation -> context
                .buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(violation.getMessage())
                .addConstraintViolation());
        return violations.isEmpty();
    }
```

So in case the `jobType` enum is `EXPORT`, it should evaluate `exportData` which is another DTO.

I also have a custom error handler; which works fine on top level validations. This is done by overwriting `handleMethodArgumentNotValid`:

I read the `BindingResult` there and its `FieldErrors`. However, I notice for my nested object in this case, it does not appear in the FieldErrors.

(code snippet):

```
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatusCode status, WebRequest request) {

        BindingResult bindingResult = ex.getBindingResult();
        final List<FieldError> fieldErrors = bindingResult.getFieldErrors();
// this does not show any errors for nested objects
```

Ideally I want the result to be a path to the property which is invalid. FieldName could be the name itself.

What did I miss?

BTW: whenever I try to set `propertyNode` in the validator, like so:

```
        violations.forEach(violation -> context
                .buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(violation.getMessage())
                .addPropertyNode(violation.getPropertyPath().toString())
                .addConstraintViolation());
```

I get an error as well (`java.lang.IllegalStateException: JSR-303 validated property .... does not have a corresponding accessor for Spring data binding - check your DataBinder's configuration (bean property versus direct field access)`) which I also can't seem to resolve. (I tried several SO answers).

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and how to fix it. The nested object must have an annotation `@Valid` within my parent object. I did not do that because it seemed a duplication to me. I also do not want to validate the object everytime, and I thought `@Valid` would act like a `this is a required field`. But it doesn't.

Adding the annotation works and gives me expected path properties as a bonus.

[This answer helped give me some context.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47202411/214597)